# add startup service on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, startup, services, nodejs, npm

i need to run "node js" project on 16.4 Permanently

and use [forever package](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) for run in background in ubuntu

now I want add a startup service to ubuntu but i searched there is no result.

I've created a file called `test.conf` to `/etc/init.d`

test.conf :

```
start on startup
exec forever start /root/node/node_modules/.bin/www
```

Comment: You will need to use a `systemd service` for this.

Comment: Will you be using `mysql`

Comment: @George There are training in this topic?

Comment: What topic are you referring to, have you set up `forever` and just need a way to run it in Ubuntu service?

Comment: @George yes ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the simplest for using `systemd service`:

1. Install `forever`:

   ```
   [sudo] npm install forever -g
   ```
2. Write and store the script to run in preferred location.
3. Write the `Systemd service`:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=forever service
   After=network.target


   [Service]
   ExecStart=/home/george/.npm-global/bin/forever start /root/node/node_modules/.bin/www
   ExecStop=/home/george/.npm-global/bin/forever stop /root/node/node_modules/.bin/www
   Restart=always
   RestartSec=10                       # Restart service after 10 seconds if node service crashes
   StandardOutput=syslog               # Output to syslog
   StandardError=syslog                # Output to syslog
   SyslogIdentifier=nodejs-example


   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
4. Save the `systemd service` file in `/etc/systemd/system` as `myforever.service` ( or with whatever name you like ).
5. Start the service and enable at start up.

   ```
   sudo systemctl start myforever.service
   sudo systemctl enable myforever.service
   ```
6. Check if it's running:

   ```
   sudo systemctl status myforever.service
   ```
7. To stop and disable it any time:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop myforever.service
   sudo systemctl disable myforever.service
   ```

**NOTE:**

1. This is a simplified version of a `systemd service` many options are available
2. The service can also be called `myforever` without the `.service` extension, `systemd` will pick the right file
3. This `/home/george/.npm-global/bin/forever` is where my `node` modules are kept, yours will be different. Find it with `which forever`

Additional Information:

https://www.axllent.org/docs/view/nodejs-service-with-systemd/

Comment: finally i use package "service-systemd"

Answer (score 0):

i use "forever service-systemd " because my ubuntu is 16.04

first use : package --> forever
and check this pages :

if upstart : https://github.com/zapty/forever-service

if systemd : https://www.npmjs.com/package/service-systemd